# Compress and download .tar file from webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, bash

I would like to create a webpage from where I can download a .tar file from the webserver (apache). The problem is that I want the .tar file to be created "on the fly" before the file is downloaded.

To solve this I have created a .php file that first calls exec() to execute a shell script available on the server that creates the .tar file and then downloads the file to the browser. This works but while the tar file is being created the webpage is not responsive and I get no status.

To solve this I have now created a html-file thar uses JavaScript/AJAX to call the .php file and wait for it to return. This works but my solution feels very complicated. Any ideas to make this easier?

Comment: Could we see your existing code? If it's public, could you link us to the site in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not add any code so I will give you plain old php.

You could stream the tar response:

```
<?php
// Your file header() here
echo passthru("tar -cfO yourpathtocompress");
```